# I want to change placeholder text in Combo Box in winRT development

Tags: winrt-xaml

I want the foregroud color of Placeholder is Foreground="#ffae19". But i get it in black color.
Can any one have solution for this :-)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectLanguage" Background="#5d198e" Foreground="#ffae19" PlaceholderText="   SELECT LANGUAGE" Width="280" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  DropDownOpened="selectLanguage_Click">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="#5d198e" Width="280" Height="40">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#ffae19" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding languageName}" ></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override these default resource keys to set the color of the placeholder text without retemplating the control:

```
<StaticResource x:Key="ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ComboBoxPlaceHolderForegroundFocusedPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit the default styles of he combobox. Use blend for that, right click on the combobox->edit style. you will get the default style. Look out for placeholder style, and change it accordingly.

Comment: This is overkill for changing a color. If you edit the entire style, you will not get any future bug fixes/updates, which can cause problems down the road.